# Properly disposing resources used by SmtpClient

Tags: email, send, smtpclient, mailmessage

I have a **C# service** that **runs continuously** with user credentials (i.e not as localsystem - I can't change this though I want to). For the most part the service seems to run ok, but ever so often it bombs out and **restarts for no apparent reason** (servicer manager is set to restart service on crash).

I am doing substantial **event logging**, and I have a **layered approach** to **Exception handling** that I believe makes at least some sort of sense:

- Essentially I got the **top level** generic exception, null exception and startup exception handlers.
- Then I got various handlers at the "**command level**" (i.e specific actions that the service runs)
- Finally I handle a few exceptions handled at the **class level**

I have been looking at whether any resources aren't properly released, and I am starting to suspect my mailing code (send email). I noticed that I was not calling Dispose for the **MailMessage object**, and I have now rewritten the SendMail code as illustrated below.

The **basic question** is:

- **will this code properly release all resources used to send mails?**
- I don't see a way to **dispose** of the **SmtpClient object**?
- (for the record: I am not using object initializer to make the sample easier to read)

```cs
    private static void SendMail(string subject, string html)
    {
        try
        {
            using ( var m = new MailMessage() )
            {
                m.From = new MailAddress("service@company.com");
                m.To.Add("user@company.com");
                m.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                m.Subject = subject;
                m.Body = html;
                var smtp = new SmtpClient("mailhost");
                smtp.Send(m);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MyMailException("Mail error.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question is pre .Net 4 but version 4 now supports a Dispose method that properly sends a quit to the smpt server. See the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.dispose.aspx) and [a newer stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781103/c-how-to-correctly-dispose-of-an-smtpclient).

Answer (score 1):

There are [documented issues](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=146711) with the SmtpClient class. I recommend buying a third party control since they aren't too expensive. Chilkat makes a decent one.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I might have to look at that. It's strange that the MailMessage object implements IDisposable, but the SmtpClient does not.

Comment: Yeah. There seems to be a work around posted on that link. May want to check that out.