# C# how to correctly dispose of an SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

VS 2010 code analysis reports the following:

Warning 4   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'Mailer.SendMessage()', object 'client' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'client' before all references to it are out of scope.

My code is :

```
public void SendMessage()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Send(Message);
        client.Dispose(); 
        DisposeAttachments(); 
    }
```

How should I correctly dispose of client?

**Update:** to answer Jons question, here is the dispose attachments functionality:

```
private void DisposeAttachments()
{
    foreach (Attachment attachment in Message.Attachments)
    {
        attachment.Dispose();
    }
    Message.Attachments.Dispose();
    Message = null; 
}
```

**Last Update** full class listing (its short)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;

public class Mailer
{
    public MailMessage Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Mailer(MailMessage message)
    {
        this.Message = message; 
    }

    public void SendMessage()
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Send(Message);
        }
        DisposeAttachments(); 
    }

    private void DisposeAttachments()
    {
        foreach (Attachment attachment in Message.Attachments)
        {
            attachment.Dispose();
        }
        Message.Attachments.Dispose();
        Message = null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: @JL - instead of disposing attachments manually you should be disposing the mailmessage itself which disposes attachments, alternate views, and other pieces.

Comment: True but in legacy version (pre .net 4.0) SmtpClient didn't implement a Dispose method

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Send(Message);
    }
    DisposeAttachments(); 
}
```

That way the client will be disposed even if an exception is thrown during the `Send` method call. You should very rarely need to call `Dispose` explicitly - it should almost always be in a `using` statement.

However, it's not clear how the attachments are involved here. Does your class implement `IDisposable` itself? If so, that's probably the place to dispose of the attachments which are presumably member variables. If you need to make absolutely sure they get disposed right here, you probably need:

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    try
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Send(Message);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        DisposeAttachments(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @JL: Hmm... it still feels like the attachments should be disposed as part of the *instance* being disposed, probably. Your `DisposeAttachments` message also means you can't get at the message afterwards, which sounds a little odd...

Comment: once the message is sent, I have no need for an instance to message or attachments. Should I rather implement a destructor?

Comment: `SmtpClient` does not implement `IDisposable` :-)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. According to Darin Dimitrov it does implement IDisposable in .NET 4.0. It didn't in .NET 3.5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Comment: JFYI: Keep in mind that if connection to smtp-server is down, the exception is sometimes thrown during calling `.Dispose()`, not `.Send()`. So keep the whole `using` block inside a `try-catch`, no just the `Send()` call.

Comment: @jitbit: Only if you *want* to catch that exception rather than letting it bubble up...

Comment: @JonSkeet of course you're right. Just wanted to emphasize, that IF you want to catch connection-errors - keep the "dispose()" call inside the TRY-block. Which is NOT something people expect.

Answer (score 13):

The `SmtpClient` class in .NET 4.0 now implements `IDisposable`, while the `SmtpClient` class in .NET 2.0 lacks this interface (as Darin noted). This is a breaking change in the framework and you should take appropriate actions when migrating to .NET 4.0. However, it is possible to mitigate this in your code before migrating to .NET 4.0. Here is an example of such:

```
var client = new SmtpClient();

// Do not remove this using. In .NET 4.0 SmtpClient implements IDisposable.
using (client as IDisposable)
{
    client.Send(message);
}
```

This code will compile and run correctly both under .NET 2.0 (+3.0 and 3.5) and under .NET 4.0.

Comment: But... will it help with actually disposing the client correctly?

Comment: Because the real issue with the earlier 3.5 version is that it doesn't send a QUIT message to the server, causing the server to keep waiting for communications. This apparently causes problems when then reconnecting to the same server.

Comment: @Nyerguds: This construct will not fix that of course.

Comment: By the way, while this will compile, you must keep in mind that "as" is a safe cast which in case of failure _returns null_. Meaning, sure, it'll compile in pre-4.0, but it might make `client` null at that point if the cast fails, causing a null reference error right after that.

Comment: @Nyerguds and what exactly will be null when that cast fails? The whole idea of this construct is to work in both scenarios (with and without disposable). There will not be any NullRefEx in that case.

Comment: Well, `using` specifies the object it'll try to dispose at the end of the operation... and in this case, that's `client as IDisposable`, AKA, null in .net 3.5. I haven't actually tested this, but unless the `using` system specifically checks that, I'd imagine that could give an error at the moment it tries to call `Dispose()` on that null.

Comment: @Nyerguds: Instead of imaginening, why won't you test it, like I have done before writing down this answer?

Answer (score 10):

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Send(Message);
    DisposeAttachments(); 
}
```

Interesting - contrary to .NET 3.5, [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) in .NET 4.0, learning new things every day.

Comment: @Darin main benefit is that SMTP client now sends the QUIT command finally during a dispose :) very happy about this!

Comment: @Darin: WTF?? SmtpClient implements IDisposable in .NET 4.0??? This is a pretty big breaking change. This hurts.

Comment: @Steven, yes and it seems at last it properly closes the connection by sending the QUIT command to the server.

Comment: Tsk, tsk, tsk, IDisposable abuse.  The System.Net team has no shame.

Comment: Be warned - if you're not using the Network delivery method, and you haven't set the Host property, then the Dispose method will throw an InvalidOperationException! http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/539160/smtpclient-reports-invalidoperationexception-when-disposed-immediatelly-after-sending-mail-and-pickup-directory-is-used

Comment: Link from @RichardDeeming is dead but can be found on the waybackmachine. Apparently  the bug in Dispose was fixed in .NET 4.5 https://web.archive.org/web/20130724055045/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/539160/smtpclient-reports-invalidoperationexception-when-disposed-immediatelly-after-sending-mail-and-pickup-directory-is-used

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like that:

```
class Attachments : List<Attachment>, IDisposable
{
  public void Dispose()
  {
    foreach (Attachment a in this)
    {
      a.Dispose();
    }
  }
}

class Mailer : IDisposable
{
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  Attachments attachments = new Attachments();

  public SendMessage()
  {
    [... do mail stuff ...]
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    this.client.Dispose();
    this.attachments.Dispose();
  }
}


[... somewhere else ...]
using (Mailer mailer = new Mailer())
{
  mailer.SendMail();
}
```

This would allow reusing the SmtpClient Object if you want to send multiple mails.

Answer (score 3):

This is the neater solution that will pass the code police test (and dispose will always be called if Send fails):

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
    {   
        client.Send(Message);
        DisposeAttachments(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My original problem is about intermittent sending failures.
E.g. First `Send()` succeeds, 2nd `Send()` fails, 3rd `Send()` succeeds.
Initially I thought I wasn't disposing properly.
So I resorted to `using()`.

Anyways, later I added the `UseDefaultCredentials = false,` and the `Send()` finally became stable. I still retained the `using()` function.

Answer (score -4):

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    try
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Send(Message);
        client.dispose()

        }
    }
    finally
    {
        DisposeAttachments(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, try to provide your code only answer with some description

Comment: Calling `Dispose()` inside a `using` block seems completely redundant.