# How to dispose an SmtpClient in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient

I am using `SmtpClient`  to send mail. How can I dispose `SmtpClient`. I am using .NET 3.5.

```
 try
     {
         smtpClient.Send(message);
         Log.WriteSpecialLog("smtpClient mail sending try success", "");
     }
      catch (Exception ee)
     {
         Log.WriteSpecialLog("smtpClient mail sending try Failed : " + ee.ToString(), "");
         return false;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET 3.5, not being able to proper dispose the SmtpClient is a know issue. 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/146711/smtp-never-sends-the-quit-command

Your question is similar to this one: [Properly disposing resources used by SmtpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128390/properly-disposing-resources-used-by-smtpclient)

The issue has been fixed in .NET 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.100).aspx and for this (and many other reasson) it would be advisible to update the .NET Framework (althought I personally know that sometimes upgrading is an issue).

But, if you really want to dispose the `SmtpClient`, you can make the class disposable yourself. But I don't know how well this goes for `SmtpClient`.
http://forums.asp.net/t/383218.aspx/1
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx

As a side note, I would advise you to handle the catch `SmtpFailedRecipientsException`, not treat exceptions generic. The `SmtpStatusCode` in the `InnerException` gives you important informations.

Comment: I have wrote to catch the inner exception.Let see what will be the issue

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, though. Being stuck with 3.5, what can I do? All the relevant properties needed to actually send that QUIT message are inaccessible (internal), so even subclassing won't work to access them.