# Dispose method for smtpclient in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, dispose, smtpclient

How to release resources 
of system.net.mail.smtpclient in .net 2.0. It does not have dispose method in .net 2.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dispose an SmtpClient in .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267644/how-to-dispose-an-smtpclient-in-net-3-5)

Comment: Hi dnickless. There is no solution for this in the link u gave. Finally it suggests to dispose mailmessage object but not smtpclient. It suggests to use .net 4.0 smtpclient which I cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To release SMTPClient resources iam making the SMTPClient object as Null and then calling. GC.Collect. this will release the smtpclient resources.

Answer (score 0):

Dispose was not added for the SMTPClient until .Net 4.0

If you're stuck with 2.0 you'll need to use a workaround.

The example used by Microsoft does not attempt to release resources, it relies most likely on garbage collection.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

You could use a tool like WireShark to check the SMTPClient is at least ending sessions with the SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Terry.  To release SMTPClient resources iam making the SMTPClient  object as Null and then calling. GC.Collect. I believe this will release the smtpclient resources?

Comment: I think that should work, it is the best approach if you cannot switch to .NET 4.0, and I know this is not possible for many projects, I work on several cont that cannot be upgraded so I know your pain!